# Firing RTK dispatch after condition is true?

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-toolkit

I have a RTK query that takes a few seconds to fetch the data.  When isSuccess is true I am then trying to fire a dispatch.

```
const router = useRouter();
const num = router.query.id;
const { data, error, isLoading, isSuccess } = useModByIdQuery(num);
const dispatch = useDispatch();

  {
    isSuccess && dispatch(addCurrentMod(data));
  }
```

The problem with this is it fires multiple times (4 to be exact).  I tried putting it in a useEffect but as the data takes a few seconds to fetch the dispatch errors out (as it's undefined).

I am not really sure the best way to approach fixing this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

RTK will keep firing request once component is loaded,
it will also keep firing even if input params is not available,

this can be controlled by [`skip` params for conditional fetching](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/usage/conditional-fetching#overview)

```
const Pokemon = ({ name, address }) => {
  const { data, error, status } = useGetPokemonByNameQuery(name, {
    skip : (!name || !address),
  });

  return (
    <div>
      {name} - {status}
    </div>
  );
};
```

If name OR address not available then it will skip api call

Answer (score 0):

First of all, given information is not enough to understand what you are trying to do. still I can see your response depends of isSuccess true and if you will console isSuccess you will found multiple true false values, so try get last value only (check for place which are effecting isSuccess API call)

Comment: Apologies.  I am trying to fetch the data through the RTK query and then when I have the data, dispatch it to the redux store.  The problem is the data takes some time to come in so it cannot be done on mount, hence trying to do it the way I am above but as you are aware, isSuccess is firing multiple times.  I will try and narrow down why that is.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).